# SwiftUI: why can't I map views in a previews in PreviewProvider?

Tags: swiftui, preview

I know that I can display several previews doing this:

```
struct TestView: View {
    let number: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange
            Text("\(number)")
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .font(.system(size: 56.0))
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView(number: 3)
        TestView(number: 5)
    }
}
```

But why can't I, instead, write this instead?

```
static var previews: some View {
    [3, 5].map { TestView(number: $0) }
}
```

(I'm getting this error: Return type of static property 'previews' requires that '[TestView]' conform to 'View')

Thank you for your help

Comment: The error is pretty clear, an array of views is not a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[TestView]`, also known as `Array<TestView>`, does not conform to `View`.

SwiftUI's solution is the `ForEach` view:

```
static var previews: some View {
    ForEach([3, 5], id: \.self) {
        TestView(number: $0)
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes every element of the array is unique (which is true in this example).

Answer (score 0):

Because it's return type is array of TestView and arrays not conform the View.

You can do it like this:

```
static var previews: some View {
    Group {
        let numbers = [3, 5]
        ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
            TestView(number: number)
        }
    }
}
```